# Correct way to get the height of an Item based on it's contents in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

This maybe a silly question, but im developing an accordion like component, where i pass with the property `content` the contents i want it to have.
the problem is when i click on the element when it opens i'm not finding how i can get the height of those items.

An example when its closed:

[image]
example when open:

[image]

Here we see that `panel 2` component should go down

The code in `main.qml` is:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabbars")

    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill:parent
        PanelItem {
            id:panel1
            title: "Panel 1"
            anchors.top:parent.top
            anchors.left:parent.left
            anchors.right:parent.right
            content: Item {
                property string title: "teste"
                anchors.fill:parent
                height:configContent.implicitHeight
                ColumnLayout{
                    id:configContent
                    anchors.fill:parent
                    TextField {
                        id: companyNameText1
                        placeholderText: qsTr("Company name")
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        selectByMouse: true
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: languagesComboBox1
                        textRole: "text"
                        objectName: "language"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        model: ListModel {
                            ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("English"); oid: 0}
                            ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Portuguese"); oid: 1}
                            ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Spanish"); oid: 2}
                            ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Italian"); oid: 3}
                            ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("French"); oid: 4}
                            ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Portuguese(Brasil)"); oid: 5}
                        }
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: devSndrModeComboBox1
                        textRole: "text"
                        objectName: "test_dev_sndr_mode"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        model: ListModel {
                            Component.onCompleted: {
                                append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("None"), oid: 0 })
                                append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("Subpanel"), oid: 1 })
                                append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("All"), oid: 2 })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                resetOtherAccordions.connect(panel2.resetHeight)
                console.log("panel 1 height "+panel1.height)
            }
        }
        PanelItem {
            id:panel2
            title: "Panel 2"
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            anchors.top:panel1.bottom
            anchors.left:parent.left
            anchors.right:parent.right
            content: Item {
                property string title: "teste"
                anchors.fill:parent
                height:configContent2.implicitHeight
                ColumnLayout{
                    id:configContent2
                    anchors.fill:parent
                    ComboBox {
                        id: sndrModeComboBox1
                        textRole: "text"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        model: ListModel {
                            Component.onCompleted: {
                                append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("Preset"), oid: 0 })
                                append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("Programmed"), oid: 1 })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                resetOtherAccordions.connect(panel1.resetHeight)
                console.log("panel 2 height "+panel2.height)
            }
        }


    }
}
```

the code in `PanelItem.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item {
    default property var contentItem: null
    property Component content
    property string title: "panel"
    id: root
    height: 30
    property bool current: false
    signal resetOtherAccordions()
    function resetHeight(){
        root.children[0].children[1].visible = false
        root.children[0].children[1].height = 0
        root.current = false
    }
        Rectangle {
            id: bar
            anchors.top:root.top
            anchors.left:root.left
            anchors.right:root.right
            height: 30
            color:  root.current ? "#81BEF7" : "#CEECF5"
            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 10
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: root.title
            }
            Text {
                anchors{
                    right: parent.right
                    top: parent.top
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                    margins: 10
                }
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: "^"
                rotation: root.current ? "180" : 0
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: bar
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                onClicked: {
                    root.current = !root.current; //toggle ao current
                    resetOtherAccordions()
                    if(root.current) {
                        root.children[1].visible = true
                        root.children[1].height = root.children[1].children[0].children[0].height
                        console.log("childrenRect height of: "+root.children[1].children[0].children[0].height)//gives 0
                        console.log("height of: "+root.children[1].children[0].children[0].childrenRect.height)//gives 0
                        console.log("title of: "+root.children[1].children[0].children[0].title)//gives teste
                        root.height = 30+root.children[1].height
                    }
                    else {
                        root.children[1].visible = false
                        root.children[1].height = 0
                        root.height = 30
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: container
            anchors.top:bar.bottom
            anchors.left:root.left
            anchors.right:root.right
            color:"white"
            height:0
            visible:false
            Loader {
                id: yourLoader
                anchors.fill:container
                anchors.top:container.top
                sourceComponent: root.content
            }
            Behavior on height {
                PropertyAnimation { duration: 100 }
            }
        }
}
```

What am i missing? thanks

Comment: Did you tried using `childrenRect` ?

Comment: Yes, but maybe not the right way, where would you put it?

Comment: Really I don't know. i have not played with QML for a few months and complex handling of size propagation is always messy, mainly because it is easy to propagate size from parent to children and from children to parent at the same time and mess up completely the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you are complicating yourself too much, the basic idea is that the height of the PanelItem is the height of the content plus the bar, and that with the loader you hide the content when necessary.

**PanelItem.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item {
    id: root
    property Component content
    property string title: "panel"
    property bool isSelected: false
    height: container.height + bar.height
    Rectangle{
        id: bar
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        height: 30
        color:  root.isSelected ? "#81BEF7" : "#CEECF5"
        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            text: root.title
        }
        Text {
            anchors{
                right: parent.right
                top: parent.top
                bottom: parent.bottom
                margins: 10
            }
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            text: "^"
            rotation: root.isSelected ? "180" : 0
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
            onClicked: isSelected = !isSelected
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        id: container
        anchors.top: bar.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: loader.item && isSelected ? loader.item.height : 0
        Loader {
            id: loader
            visible: isSelected
            sourceComponent: content
            anchors.top: container.top
        }
        Behavior on height {
            PropertyAnimation { duration: 100 }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabbars")
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill:parent
        Column{
            anchors.fill: parent
            PanelItem{
                width: parent.width
                title: "Panel 1"
                content: Item {
                    property string title: "teste"
                    height: configContent.implicitHeight
                    width: configContent.implicitWidth
                    ColumnLayout{
                        id:configContent
                        width: root.width
                        //anchors.fill:parent
                        TextField {
                            id: companyNameText1
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Company name")
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            selectByMouse: true
                        }
                        ComboBox {
                            id: languagesComboBox1
                            textRole: "text"
                            objectName: "language"
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            model: ListModel {
                                ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("English"); oid: 0}
                                ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Portuguese"); oid: 1}
                                ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Spanish"); oid: 2}
                                ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Italian"); oid: 3}
                                ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("French"); oid: 4}
                                ListElement {text: QT_TR_NOOP("Portuguese(Brasil)"); oid: 5}
                            }
                        }
                        ComboBox {
                            id: devSndrModeComboBox1
                            textRole: "text"
                            objectName: "test_dev_sndr_mode"
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            model: ListModel {
                                Component.onCompleted: {
                                    append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("None"), oid: 0 })
                                    append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("Subpanel"), oid: 1 })
                                    append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("All"), oid: 2 })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            PanelItem{
                width: parent.width
                title: "Panel 1"
                content: Item {
                    property string title: "teste"
                    height:configContent2.implicitHeight
                    width: configContent2.implicitWidth
                    ColumnLayout{
                        id:configContent2
                        width: root.width
                        ComboBox {
                            id: sndrModeComboBox1
                            textRole: "text"
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            model: ListModel {
                                Component.onCompleted: {
                                    append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("Preset"), oid: 0 })
                                    append({ text: QT_TR_NOOP("Programmed"), oid: 1 })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]